# Where are the stats for gearforged and warforged?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races, warforged

I am playing 5e. I want to make a gearforged or warforged damage dealing character, probably fighter or paladin. Where would I look to find the stats or race page for the gearforged or warforged races?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Ask your DM, if he/she allows UA

Faerûn and Ravenloft are the only 5e settings with official published material to date, and there are no warforged native to Faerun or Ravenloft. Your DM might choose the Eberron setting, and if they do, they probably will use the related [Unearthed Arcana materials](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Eberron_v1.pdf), where you can find the warforged race description. (You have to ask because Unearthed Arcana is unfinished playtesting material.)

Your DM also might homebrew the race; ask your DM for the details.

Comment: As of the release of the Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron (as a "living document"), the warforged now appear in it as a race option for the Eberron setting.

Comment: Note: the warforged have been changed substantially and published in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, and the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* has been updated to match.

Answer (score 9):

With the release of the [Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/247882/Wayfinders-Guide-to-Eberron-5e) for 5E, there are now official rules for the Warforged Race.

See [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/warforged) for Warforged race details. The same information appears on p. 67-70 of the PDF version from DMsGuild.

Comment: Note to readers: the warforged have been changed substantially and published in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, and the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* has been updated to match.